extracting individuals with Plink 1.9: error Error: No people remaining after --keep
I am trying to subset my data (combnhwtot_ld.ped) down to just the samples in my phenotype file (m3_nhw_tot.pheno) then convert these files to binary format using the following line of code in plink v1.9:
plink --file combnhwtot_ld --keep m3_nhw_tot.pheno --make-bed --out nhw_all_id_sub
However, I keep receiving the following error message:
Error: No people remaining after --keep.
my keep file is in this following format (space delim):



FID
IID
pheno




XYZ456754
XYZ456754
0


XYZ617811
XYZ617811
0


XYZ641724
XYZ641724
0


XYZ674621
XYZ674621
0



I have tried inputting the phenotype data into my plink argument with and without the header, but I still receive the same error message.  I have also double checked to make sure that the samples in the keep file are actually present in the genotype data and they are.
